# Problemas al logearme en mi página web

Tags: php, mysql, seguridad

He modificado mi código para protegerme de las inyecciones SQL, pero ahora no me permite loguearme a mi página de inicio.

Aquí dejo mi código del script encargado de validar los datos, pero al momento de ir a mi página de inicio me muestra el mensaje que aun no me he logueado.

```php
<?php
/* start the session */
//ob_start();

session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Check Login</title>
 <meta charset = "utf8" />
</head>


<body>

<?php

$servername = "*******";
$username = "********";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "******";

$username2 = $_POST['username'];
$password2 = $_POST['password'];
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  FROM usuarios WHERE username=? AND password=?")) {

    // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username2, $password2);

    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the variables from the query.
    $stmt->bind_result($username2);
    $stmt->bind_result($password2);

    // Fetch the data.
    $stmt->fetch();


 $_SESSION['username'] = $username2;
 $_SESSION['start'] = time();
 $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (30 * 60) ;
    // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Aquí dejo el form:

```html
introduzca sus credenciales para operar el sistema.</div>
  <form id="form1" name="form1"  action="checklogin.php" method="post"  autocomplete="off" >
    <table width="200" id="m"   border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="us"></label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="USUARIO" required="required" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="textfield"></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA" required="required" /></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td> <input type="submit" class="button" name="send2" id="send2"  value="Ingresar" />  </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: 1) Seguro que esa consulta funciona como está? Ese `Select FROM` va a dar error de sintaxis. 2) No veo el formulario. ¿Estás seguro que recibes la contraseña en el mismo formato que la guardaste? Ejemplo: el post puede traer un clear text y en la BD puede estar ya como un hash.

Comment: Actualicé el comentario :) Y por favor, añade el código relevante editando la pregunta, no en un comentario

Comment: Ya incluí el form

Comment: ¿Agregaste `*` entre `SELECT FROM` (o cualesquiera que sean los campos que quieres)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay al menos dos errores en tu código.

### Error 1: sintaxis de la instrucción SQL

Debes especificar las columnas que quieres seleccionar en tu instrucción SQL:

```
SELECT username, password FROM usuarios WHERE username=? AND password=?
```

Dado que luego vas a asignar el valor de cada columna a una variable con `bind_result`, en este caso no te sirve usar `SELECT * ...`, debes sí o sí especificar cada columna que necesitas, y por cada columna debes indicar una variable que recogerá su valor respectivo en `bind_result`.

### Error 2: Mal uso de `bind_result`

Si haces binding de los valores por separado, tendrás este mensaje:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind
>   variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement -- at
>   line ...
>
> E_WARNING : type 2 -- mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind
>   variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement -- at
>   line ...

No es un error desde el punto de vista de PHP, es un Warning. Pero sí es un error desde el punto de vista de tu programa, porque no podrás acceder al valor de cada columna como esperas para hacer luego la comprobación.

Debes hacer un sólo `bind_result`, poniendo cada variable separada por comas:

```
$stmt->bind_result($username2,$password2);
```

También, yo pondría esto:

```
$stmt->close();
```

inmediatamente después del `fetch`, antes de pasar a trabajar con las variables de sesión.

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)  esto es lo que tengo en mi pagina de inicio despues de validar la info con la base de datos y aun asi me dice que no estoy logueado

Comment: @LeonardoRodríguez ¿Corregiste y probaste la info que traes de la base de datos? ¿Ya la trae bien? Nunca he trabajado con sesiones, por tanto de eso no puedo decirte gran cosa, pero me extraña que en el planteamiento de la pregunta uses: `$_SESSION['username']`  y luego comentes que estás evaluando `$_SESSION['loggedin']` ... ¿? Como digo, nunca he usado sesiones, pero supongo que debes usar `session_start();` y cosas de ese tipo. El código que has mostrado tenía los dos problemas que mencione en cuanto a la base de datos. Es necesario que verifiques que eso se resolvió...

Comment: coloqué todo lo que me dijiste pero ahora cualquier "usuario" puede loguearse

Comment: @LeonardoRodríguez te faltan verificaciones... [mira por ejemplo este tutorial completo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm)

Comment: Gracias, con ese tutorial fue suficiente

Comment: @LeonardoRodríguez me alegro de que hayas podido resolver el problema. Saludos.